# Running a python file to train GAN using reinforcement learning

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I'm reading the Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands-On book by Maxim Lapan but have trouble running code [here](https://github.com/Shmuma/Deep-Reinforcement-Learning-Hands-On/blob/master/Chapter03/03_atari_gan.py). I get the following error when running this file. I'm new to ubuntu's command line and PyTorch but I'm familiar to Deep Learning. Please help me solve this problem. Thank you!

I tried to run this file using python 03_atari_gan.py

How do I pass 'mode' while running the program?
Thanks!

> INFO: Making new env: Breakout-v0 INFO: Making new env: AirRaid-v0
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "03_atari_gan.py", line 138,
>   in 
>       envs = [InputWrapper(gym.make(name)) for name in ('Breakout-v0', 'AirRaid-v0', 'Pong-v0')]   File "03_atari_gan.py", line 138, in
>   
>       envs = [InputWrapper(gym.make(name)) for name in ('Breakout-v0', 'AirRaid-v0', 'Pong-v0')]   File
>   "/home/sandesh/rl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py",
>   line 156, in make
>       return registry.make(id, **kwargs)   File "/home/sandesh/rl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py",
>   line 101, in make
>       env = spec.make(**kwargs)   File "/home/sandesh/rl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/registration.py",
>   line 73, in make
>       env = cls(**_kwargs)   File "/home/sandesh/rl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py",
>   line 69, in **init**
>       self.seed()   File "/home/sandesh/rl/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gym/envs/atari/atari_env.py",
>   line 98, in seed
>       ).format(self.game_mode, self.game, modes) AssertionError: Invalid game mode "0" for game air_raid. Available modes are: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7
>   8]

Comment: The error message is clear: "AssertionError: **Invalid game mode "0"** for game air_raid. Available modes are: [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]". What is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your response. How do I pass the mode to the program via command line?